# How to use Twitter as the Login for a Website

Tags: asp.net, twitter, oauth

We are developing an asp.net 2.0 web application in that user can sign-up or sign-in using twitter account.

when the user click on the twitter button, it should take you to the twitter login page.
after your login is successful twitter should able to forward me back to my page webpage.

Please let me know.

eg.
[twitter](http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_nonce=30503696&oauth_timestamp=1251224001&oauth_consumer_key=IhIL55Of0csSoKKOSxZcuA&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_token=clfeI2Q6stwNmULN6TdmXwUFdI8TQHBcfAtRoC0zMBw&oauth_signature=kP55sZ6mFc34DODE1%2Bk/F7ySkDE%3D)

Comment: Please let you know what? How to do it for you? You have to ask a question.

Comment: @JoshJordan I thought it was pretty clear. He wants to know how to implement a Facebook Connect-style system for Twitter.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this you use Twitter's [OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq) authentication framework. It's used so that users don't have to directly enter their user + password into your site. (I assume you know how the front-end to that works already.)

You can use [this little example](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=681) to use OAuth from .NET - it is built for ASP.NET. (The demo the guy provides is [My Tweeple](http://mytweeple.com/default.aspx).)

Comment: This is more kind of a user updating status to his twitter account using oAuth. But i am trying to implement like a facbook connect.

for eg. to to friendfeed.com and click on the twitter button.

Comment: @Lucas Jones I am getting a user_id for twitter ? It seems to be of different length for different users. Is that a unique id ? Can i use as a unique identity to add an account in my db ?

Answer (score 4):

Twitter actually [includes instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter) for using OAuth to make a Facebook Connect-style system.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter

Answer (score 0):

[Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) library have sample ASP.NET application that will walk you through the OAuth     authorization process and attempt to explain what’s going on and how you can do the same in your application.

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202220645/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051210-1.aspx) demonstrates that How to integrate Twitter into web application
using Twitterizer library.You can allow your visitors to post tweets, view their timeline and much more.

[Here](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/) is an example shows how to implement Twitter OAuth with .NET and attached sample code.